# watchos sometimes not showing image

Tags: swift, xcode, watchos

I've create a very simple app that is supposed to show image and timer when application becomes active.

I have some images stored in WatchKit extension `Assets.xcassets`. I have also added second interface screen that is also supposed to show just an image. I'm then updating the `WKInterfaceImage` with call of the function `setImageNamed`, but here comes the tricky part, after swipe i get **sometimes** just the black screen instead of an image, also without timer,
the function `override func willActivate()` is being called, but the screen is just black.

I did the test also on real hardware (`4 series 44mm with watchos 6`) and got the same result.

versions:

```
macos 10.14.6
xcode 11.0
swift 5
watchos 6
```

some images for illustration:

interface storyboard:
[image: interface storyboard]

simulator before and after multiple (like 15 to 20) swipes

[image]

and some code

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import UserNotifications

class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {

    @IBOutlet weak var activityImage: WKInterfaceImage!

    @IBOutlet weak var activityCountdown: WKInterfaceTimer!

// some other irrelevant code
// ....
// ....

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        updateActivityImage()
        updateActivityCoundtdown()
        super.willActivate()
    }

    @objc private func updateActivityImage() -> Void {

        let currentMinute = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) * 60 + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())

        let indexOfNextActivity =
            Config
                .activities
                .map({ activity in return activity.time })
                .firstIndex(where: { $0 > currentMinute }) ?? 0

        let indexOfCurrentActivity = indexOfNextActivity - 1 < 0 ? Config.activities.count - 1 : indexOfNextActivity - 1

        let currentActivity = Config.activities[indexOfCurrentActivity]

        if currentActivity.hasCountdown {
            self.activityCountdown.setHidden(false)
        } else {
            self.activityCountdown.setHidden(true)
        }
        print(currentActivity.image)
        self.activityImage.setImageNamed(currentActivity.image)
    }

    @objc private func updateActivityCoundtdown() -> Void {
        let currentMinute = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date()) * 60 + Calendar.current.component(.minute, from: Date())

        let indexOfNextActivity =
            Config
                .activities
                .map({ activity in return activity.time })
                .firstIndex(where: { $0 > currentMinute }) ?? 0

        let nextActivity = Config.activities[indexOfNextActivity]

        var nextActivityTime = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year], from: Date())

        // still not fully covered, if the next activity is first in list, means the next acitivty is at another day
        if (indexOfNextActivity == 0) {
            nextActivityTime.day = nextActivityTime.day! + 1
        }
        nextActivityTime.hour = Int(nextActivity.time / 60)
        nextActivityTime.minute = nextActivity.time % 60
        let nextActitivyDate = Calendar.current.date(from: nextActivityTime as DateComponents)!

        // set refresh timer at activity end
        let countDownTimer = Timer.init(fire: nextActitivyDate, interval: 1, repeats: false, block: { reason in self.updateActivityCoundtdown();
            self.updateActivityImage();
        })
        RunLoop.current.add(countDownTimer, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.common)

        self.activityCountdown.setDate(nextActitivyDate)
        self.activityCountdown.start()
    }
```

Thanks!